# Doctrine Symfony PHP

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create

In ExceptionConverter.php line 103:
                                                                                  
  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                                                                  

In Exception.php line 30:
                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                             

In Driver.php line 28:
                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

***Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему. Когда создаешь базу данных вылазит ошибка.***

***Please tell me how to solve this problem. When you create the database you get an error**.***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ploHI.png

***.env***

```
# .env (or override DATABASE_URL in .env.local to avoid committing your changes)

# customize this line!
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"

# to use mariadb:
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.8"

# to use sqlite:
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/app.db"

# to use postgresql:
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"

# to use oracle:
# DATABASE_URL="oci8://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:1521/db_name"
```

Comment: Лучше код помещать, а не только ошибки

Comment: код есть только в файлике .env

Comment: .env - файл конфигурации, это не код) Ошибка указывает на вызов исключения, соединения нет

Comment: Все сделал как было написано на офф доке Symfony Doctrine. Скажите пожалйста как убрать эту ошибку?

Comment: Ну а просто к БД можешь подключиться, не через php-скрипт?

Comment: нет не могу....

Comment: если у вас линукс то проверьте слушает ли какой-то сервис порт 3306 этой командой ```netstat   -ab | grep 3306```

Comment: если на этом порту слушает mysql сервер. То проверьте соединение с сервером и наличие базы путем подключения к нему клиентом. Команда ```mysql -uroot -pdb_password -e 'show databases;' ``` Я указал данные для подключения, с которыми вы соединяетесь ```DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name``` Если соединения не получается, значит логин, пароль или база указаны вами некорректно

Comment: 1. а вообще mysql-сервер устанавливали на своем компьютере? 2. если устанавливали, то задавали ли ему логин/пароль? в вашем конфиге просто копипаст из руководства

Answer (score 0):

ваша ошибка говорит о том, что невозможно соединиться с базой, тут несколько вариантов:

1. вы ввели неправильные параметры соединения с базой в файлике конфигурации .env
2. у вас несколько файлов конфигурации (dev, prod, test) и данные для коннекта берутся не из того файла
3. если база удалённая, то работает ли сервер (или сервер самой базы данных)

попробуйте подключиться со сторонней программы (DBeaver, Navicat) к целевому серверу баз данных